# Arrange blocks div bootstrap 3 - col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just can not understand how to arrange the blocks so that col-sm-3 was on the sides, and col-sm-6 in the center, but the html code should go that way.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-left" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-right" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>
```

the code itself is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-left" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-right" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap V3 use float so the column are already **left floated** so only the `pull-right` will have an effect.

So why not simply change the order and **don't forget row inside container** *(I changed `sm` by `xs` so we can see the result in the reduced snippet)*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to keep the same code consider upgrading to the V4 of bootstrap where you can easily handle this with [flex and order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 order-2" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
    <div class="col-3 order-1" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
    <div class="col-3 order-3" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

By the way, You can add some custom CSS with the V3 and your intial code to achieve what you want but I don't recommend *(only use in case you cannot do any changes)*:

```css
.custom {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 custom" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you don't want to change your HTML you can use the concept of `col-push` and `col-pull` of bootstrap3

*<sup>**Note**: Remember to use a parent class for to preventing change globally in `col-*` classes. I have used a class `change` for reference here</sup>*

```css
.change .col-xs-6 {
  left: 25%;
}

.change .row .col-xs-3:not(:last-child) {
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container change">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-left" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Or in any case if you can change the HTML which I recommend use `col-push` and `col-pull` or **just put it in order***

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container change">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-3" style="background-color:red; color:#fff;">center</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-pull-6" style="background-color:blue; color:#fff;">left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:green; color:#fff;">right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in the first code the pull-left is useless and you have to remove it as this is the main issue of question, the OP is not aware about the already floated div ... and concerning the second code, i don't agree .... if we can change the html then we simply put them in the right order, why overcomplicating ? by the way you are simply changing the classes

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was waiting for your comment...;)..in first option I didn't remove the `pull-left` as OP don't want to change the HTML part....and in the second option I gave an alternate solution as you already mentioned in your answer a solution of just use in order...

Comment: yes but your second solution create a bit of confusion as you are not modifing the HTML but only adding classes I think this ok with OP as he's already playing with pull-left pull-right ... so am sure he can add classes